# How to write double lined 1

Tags: errors

I needed double lined 1 while writing a book in latex. I had installed bbm package in my desktop as directed and use the following command. However i didnot get the required one. This command was obtained from a solution but it didnot work for me. I had also attached the image which shows output in pdf.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bbm}
\begin{document}\LARGE
    \[ \mathbbm{1} \]
\end{document}
```

[image: pdf obtained]

Comment: Do you mean `\mathbb` instead of `\mathbbm`? Just use `\usepackage{amsfonts}` first.

Comment: @AJFarmar -- If using `amssymb`(which loads `amsfonts`), the command is `\bbone`.

Answer (score 3):

Please try with:

```
\usepackage{dsfont}

\mathds{1}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use the following format.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bbold}

\begin{document}
 $mathbb{1}_X $
\end{document}
```

[image: BlackBoard 1]